# How to nest a "for loop" n times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for a in range(min_num,max_num+1):
    for b in range(min_num,max_num+1):
        for c in range(min_num,max_num+1):
            for d in range(min_num,max_num+1):
                for e in range(min_num,max_num+1):
                    rows=[e,d,c,b,a]
```

how would I go about writing this such that rows can be any length?
I would like to do this without importing any modules

Comment: event built in modules like itertools?

Comment: The requirement to do it without itertools is odd, but you can always put the [same logic as `itertools.product`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2080) into your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generator solution:

```
xss = [],
for _ in range(n):
    xss = ([x] + xs for xs in xss for x in range(min_num, max_num+1))
```

Demo of using the result (with `n = 5` and `min_num, max_num = 7, 9`):

```
>>> for xs in xss:
        print(xs)

[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[8, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[9, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[7, 8, 7, 7, 7]
[8, 8, 7, 7, 7]
[9, 8, 7, 7, 7]
[7, 9, 7, 7, 7]
[8, 9, 7, 7, 7]
[9, 9, 7, 7, 7]
[7, 7, 8, 7, 7]
...
[9, 9, 8, 9, 9]
[7, 7, 9, 9, 9]
[8, 7, 9, 9, 9]
[9, 7, 9, 9, 9]
[7, 8, 9, 9, 9]
[8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
[9, 8, 9, 9, 9]
[7, 9, 9, 9, 9]
[8, 9, 9, 9, 9]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

for i in product(range(3),repeat=3):
    print(i)
```

gives you

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 0, 2)
(2, 1, 0)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
```